# Aligning captions of different sized subfigures

Tags: subcaption, subfig

I would like to make the captions of these subfigures align without changing the position of the images. Below is my script and the produced images: 
[image]

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{ppy.png}
      \caption{PPy}
      \label{fig:ppy}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{pedot.png}
      \caption{PEDOT}
      \label{fig:pedot}
    \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Caption (Lacour)(Jorfi)}
        \label{fig:mol_structures}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: The optional argument of subfigure specify the aligment of the figure. try `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}`

Comment: Actually, [t] would also work, since the first baseline is the bottom of the image.

Comment: These both also change the position of the image - is there any way of making just the caption change position

Comment: Welcome. // Please post code, which compiles, next time. Thank you